# Python SMTPLIB , SSL Library Error --> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted)

Tags: python, email, ssl, smtp, port

I got a problem with my python program. I Have entered the correct information about my email and password the program and the error is shown below

```
import smtplib, SSL 

email="belginjarosh46@gmail.com"
password="my password"
port = 465

context = ssl.create_default_context()

server =smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com",port,context=context) 
server.login(email,password)
message=" Hi I Am Belgin Android "
sender_mail=email,
receiver_email="belginjarosh46@gmail.com"
server.sendmail(sender_mail,receiver_email,message)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Belgin/Desktop/Python Coding/email_sending.py", line 10, in <module>
    server.login(email,password)
  File "G:\Python\lib\smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "G:\Python\lib\smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "G:\Python\lib\smtplib.py", line 646, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f21sm2590687pfn.71 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: did you follow all "Troubleshoot" tips in the link of the error message? Have you tried using your login data with a standalone email client?

Comment: yes sir, I tried

Comment: and did it work? I tried your exact code (except `ssl` instead of `SSL`) after creating an app specific password at https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords and everything just worked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum it up - I guess the problem was that Google does not allow you to log in with your default user password, especially (but not only) when using 2nd factor authentication.
So for using the password for 3rd party apps it [requires creating app specific passwords](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords).

Comment: Yes Sir,  Now It Worked ..  I Enabled 2 Step Verification and App Password Got enabled and Now I can use it