# smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.)

Tags: python, email, ssl, oauth-2.0, smtplib

Basically, I set 2-step verfication on Google email then I went onto set up app password. While running the following code I got an error:

I have provided username and password as examples. Actually, I gave them proper names for program to function.

```
def send_email(message):
   host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
   port = 465

   username = 'example.com'
   password = "jpcimnjhfjelzwds"

   reciever = 'example1.com'
   context = ssl.create_default_context()

   with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port, context=context) as server:
       server.login(username, password)
       server.sendmail(username, reciever, message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   send_email()
```

The following error:
`smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u3-20020ac24c23000000b004f75661a7e6sm583437lfq.36 - gsmtp')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python SMTPLIB , SSL Library Error --> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517108/python-smtplib-ssl-library-error-smtplib-smtpauthenticationerror-535-b)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have done all the steps required but still it does not complete my program and keeps sending errors.